# Recursively Rsync/copy files to different structure

Tags: bash, rsync

I have the given file structure:

```
- dev/
   - examplesite.com/
     - public/
       - file.css
       - file.jpg
  - anotherexamplesite.com/
     - public/
       - stuff.css
       - things.jpg
     - resources/
       - views/ 
         - view.php
- public/
  - examplesite.com/
    - somefile.txt
- sites/
  - examplesite.com/
```

I want to sync all of the files inside the public directory of each site folder in the `dev` directory, into the `public` directory above like so:

```
- public/
   - examplesite.com/
     - file.css
     - file.jpg
   - anotherexamplesite.com/
     - stuff.css
     - things.jpg
```

And the files in the `resources` directory into the sites folder like so:

```
- sites/
     - examplesite.com/
       - resources/
          - views/ 
            - view.php
```

Basically copying the contents of the public directory in each site up one directory, and then syncing that parent directory to the `public` directory. And copying the resources directory directly into the sites directory. I have this second part working, but the first part isn't working right:

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MY_PATH="/var/www"

rsync --exclude='.git/' "$MY_PATH/dev/" "$MY_PATH/sites/" --recursive
rsync --exclude='.git/' --exclude='resources/' "$MY_PATH/dev/public" "$MY_PATH/public/" --recursive
```

The first rsync command of this script works fine, it copies the files into the sites directory without issue, since the folder structure does not need to change. However, the second rsync command does the following:

```
- public/
   - examplesite.com/
     - public/
        - file.css
        - file.jpg
   - anotherexamplesite.com/
     - public/
       - stuff.css
       - things.jpg
```

I'm not really sure how to easily copy the files recursively into the proper site folder, while also moving the destination files out of their public dir, and up one directory so they live directly under the sitename.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with rsync alone. Even `--filter` isn't smart enough to handle translations like this. Your best bet is likely a hybrid solution as [@sapanoia](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41496391/1072112) has suggested. Though you might want to consider using a real configuration management tool for deploying sites - something like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [saltstack](https://saltstack.com/) or [chef](https://www.chef.io/) or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could mix some `bash` code with `rsync`, for example (untested, just to give you an idea):

```
for site in $MY_PATH/dev/*; do
  dist="$MY_PATH/public/$(basename "$site")"
  mkdir -p "$dist"
  rsync -r --exclude='.git/' "$site/public/" "$dist/"
done
```

This will:

- Iterate over the sites in `dev/`
- Determine the destination and store it in the variable `dist`
- Ensure that the destination directory exists
- `rsync` from `dev/` to `public/`

This snippet only handles `dev` since your example for `resources` is already working.

If you want `rsync` to also delete files from the destination which are no longer present, you may add the flag `--delete`.

Comment: I was going to suggest something like this, only using rsync `--list-only. This is much more clear and concise. :-)  One suggestion - your `--exclude` could be replaced with `--cvs-exclude`, which covers `.git` and a whole bunch of other things that are also probably inappropriate for promotion. Oh, and it's also worth mentioning that you almost never need to use `basename` and `dirname` when your shell supports parameter expansion.